# What is the fuel mass flow rate at stationary full power for the CFM56 5C2/3C1 engines?

Tags: turbofan, fuel-consumption

Does anyone know what is the value of fuel mass flow rate when stationary at full power for CFM56-5C2 or CFM65-3C1 turbofan engines? I am doing a work on engine performance and it seems that only information I can't find is the fuel flow rate at conditions above. I will be very grateful to someone who can help me.

Comment: fuel consumption times thrust?

Comment: @user3528438 You mean TSFC? If you know the TSFC at conditions above I can calculate the fuel mass flow and would resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you sure of the /3C1 part? I can't find it on the [type certificate](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/TCDS%20E.003%20issue%2004_20170928.pdf).

Comment: @ymb1 Pretty much. But -3C will also work as well I think. Any data about it would be helpfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > If you know the TSFC at conditions above I can calculate the fuel mass flow and would resolve the issue.

From [this page](https://www.jet-engine.net/civtfspec.htm), the **CFM56-5C2** used on the A340-211/-311 delivers 31,200 lbf and its SFC is 0.320 lb/lbf hr. The cruise thrust and SFC are 6,910 and 0.545 respectively.